# Yii SEO friendly language enabled urls

Tags: php, url, yii

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/) .

What I want to achieve is something like

```
http://something.com/language/controller/action
```

But I'm getting

```
http://something.com/controller/action?language=en&id=1
```

As far as I know, [here is](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/#hh0) part where URL generation goes. But I can't figure out how to fix it.

What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnConde http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/

Comment: Can you show the `urlManager` part of your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an htaccess file (if you are unfamiliar with htaccess check for a tutorial on google)

add the following lines in it

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&request=$2
```

WIth this rule lets assume you have the domain.com and a user requests the following url

http://www.domain.com/news/December/politics/Titlearticle1

The above rule will break this url request and assign

```
$_GET['page'] = 'news';
```

and

```
$_GET['request'] = '/December/politics/Titlearticle1';
```

Now in you php script

you could

1) validate the page request

2) explode $_GET['request'] to further validate your request

```
$request_parts = explode('/',$_GET['request']);
```

3) validate everything! this is very important or your site might be vulnerable.

like so:

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'news')
}
  include 'news.php';
{
else if ($_GET['page'] == 'home')
{
  include 'home.php';
}
  else
{
  include 'error.php';
}
```

This is some pretty basic concept but you can expand it according to your needs...

Answer (score 2):

As suggest by @PanagiotisGeorgeRadi you have to use the .htaccess (in the project root), mine is slight different, but the base is the same:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then in **protected/config/main.php** in the **components** array set the profile of the URL manager:

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            '<lang:(en|fr|it|es)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', // only these 4 lang codes
            '<lang:[a-z][a-z]>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>', // or a generic pattern
        ),
    ),
```

then the actions in your controller has this signature:

```
class TestController{
  public function actionIndex($lang){
    // $lang will be en|fr|es|it
    // or [a-z][a-z]
  }
}
```

Using url manager you will accept only suppoted languages without any **if** or **switch**

ADD
good documentation about UrlManager:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

The best part of the url manager is the creating link in pages, eg:

```
$url=$this->createUrl('test/index',array('lang'=>'en'));
```

will be the relative path: **en/test/index**

```
$url=$this->createAbsoluteUrl('test/index',array('lang'=>'en'));
```

will be the absolute URL **http://www.loc.dom/en/test/index** if the project is in the documentRoot or **http://www.loc.dom/sub/path/en/test/index** if placed elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd add/remove query string parameters using the defaultParams option from your url manager object.  From the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule#defaultParams-detail):

> defaultParams: the default GET parameters (name=>value) that this rule
>   provides. When this rule is used to parse the incoming request, the
>   values declared in this property will be injected into $_GET.

However, in this case, you've extended your createURL method to add these parameters manually to the end of your url, in order to provide multilingual URL support.  If you don't care about this, simply ensure that your params object is set to an empty array:

```
return parent::createUrl($route);
```